# Error with Error Handling on Excel (Type mismatch Error 13)

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error, onerror

I'm trying to execute a code on VBA that fill a cell with "-" every time he encounters a blank cell in the used Range. I have two columns with formulas inside (And the formula result is "#Value" because the user let it blank) and when I run the code I get a run-time error on the line:

```
If pl.Range(Split(Cells(1, coluna).Address, "$")(1) & linha).Value = ""
```

I tried to use Error Handler but it doesn't work. It simply ignores the tag and keeps giving me a run-time error screen. What should I do?

The error I get:

> Type mismatch (Error 13)

Thanks for the help!

```
Public Sub PreencheCaracterizacao()

Dim linha As Long
Dim coluna As Long

Set pl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BD - Caracterização")

'Two loops: linha (line) and coluna (column)
For linha = 2 To pl.Cells.Find("*", pl.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, lPrevious).Row
    For coluna = 1 To pl.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
        On Error GoTo proximo
        'Test if the cell is blank
        If pl.Range(Split(Cells(1, coluna).Address, "$")(1) & linha).Value = "" Then
            
            'Fill the cell with the string "-"
            pl.Range(Split(Cells(1, coluna).Address, "$")(1) & linha).Value = "-"
            
        End If 

proximo:
    Next coluna
Next linha 

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `lPrevious` supposed to be `xlPrevious` ? Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and then try it to find other errors.

Comment: FYI `pl.Range(Split(Cells(1, coluna).Address, "$")(1) & linha).Value` is a long way of writing `pl.Cells(linha, coluna).Value`

Comment: That is most probably becuase there is a formual error in that cell? Put a break point in that line and check which cell address is giving you the error. Then manually go to that cell and see if you have any "#" errors For example #NA #DIV etc

Comment: Possibly the error handler was already called once, and then it might ignore it the next time. Place an `On Error GoTo 0` after the code where the error may occur or after the label `proximo:`

Comment: As @braX says, but do it with _Tools, Options, Require variable declarations_ so VB will always warn when a variable is not declared (or misspelled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replace in Non-Empty Range

- When looping through the cells of a worksheet, you have to account for possible error values which will cause the 'Type mismatch error' to occur. One way to do it is illustrated in the first two solutions.
- The third (most accurate) solution uses the [`Range.Replace method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) (which is much more efficient) and the `refNonEmpty` 'helper' function.
- The last solution is a one-liner that uses the [`Worksheet.UsedRange property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange) which has its limitations.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub replaceBlanksSlow()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("BD - Caracterizaçao")
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    
    Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim coluna As Long
  
    For linha = 2 To lRow
        For coluna = 1 To lCol
            cValue = ws.Cells(linha, coluna).Value
            If Not IsError(cValue) Then
                If cValue = "" Then
                    ws.Cells(linha, coluna).Value = "-"
                End If
            End If
        Next coluna
    Next linha
    
End Sub

Sub replaceBlanksSlowConstants()

    Const wsName As String = "BD - Caracterizaçao"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const fCol As Long = 1
    Const rString As String = "-"
         
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    
    Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim coluna As Long
  
    For linha = fRow To lRow
        For coluna = fCol To lCol
            cValue = ws.Cells(linha, coluna).Value
            If Not IsError(cValue) Then
                If cValue = "" Then
                    ws.Cells(linha, coluna).Value = rString
                End If
            End If
        Next coluna
    Next linha
    
End Sub

' This one uses the 'refNonEmpty' function to create a reference to the range.
Sub replaceBlanks()

    Const wsName As String = "BD - Caracterizaçao"
    Const First As String = "A2"
    Const fCol As Long = 1
    Const rString As String = "-"
         
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(First)

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = refNonEmpty(fCell)
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        rg.Replace "", rString
    End If
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from a given cell (range)
'               to the last non-empty cell in its worksheet.
' Remarks:      It may fail if the worksheet is filtered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function refNonEmpty( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim rg As Range
        With FirstCell.Cells(1)
            Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
                .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1)
            Dim lCell As Range
            Set lCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
            Set rg = rg.Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            Set refNonEmpty = rg.Resize(, rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , _
                xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column - .Column + 1)
        End With
    End If

End Function

' Note that here you cannot control the first cell.
Sub replaceBlanksUsedRange()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BD - Caracterizaçao").UsedRange.Replace "", "-"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! all three solution have worked and the code is much more clean than mine. It helped a lot.